# Set textColor in MULTIPLE textViews

Tags: android, xml

I would like to change the textColor of a lot of textViews, and set in to red.
For now, here is my xml code, with the first textView changed to red :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data1_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latitude" 
            android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latitude_val" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data2_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Longitude" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Longitude_val" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data3_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Altitude" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Altitude_val" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data4_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vitesse GPS" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vitesse GPS_val" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the textViews are inside a Linear Layout, but sadly, you can't just use `android:textColor` in the Layout parameters.

Here I displayed only 4 textViews, but there are a lot more, and I wouldn't like to give the parameter to each one by one (imagine if I want to change the color after that...)

Is there some sort of tag to indicate a style to a bunch of textViews?

Comment: have a custom textview and set color for the same. You can use the same in your application. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: use style attribute, and in your style just define the textColor

Comment: @WhiskThimble you can also make of strings.xml to store the color value

Comment: I can, indeed, use a custom style, which helps me if I have to change the color for example, but I still have to declare the attribute 'style' in each and every textView, which can be very long compared to its usefulness

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will work for you.

```
    private void setTextColor()
    {
    /*put id(s) of all the TextView you want to change the color of,
    In an array and call setTextColor() for all the array items*/
    int textViews[]={R.id.data1_text,R.id.data1,R.id.data2_text,R.id.data2,R.id.data3_text,R.id.data3};
    for(int i=0;i<textViews.length;i++)
    ((TextView)findViewById(textViews[i])).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

Now,call `setTextColor()` from your `onCreate()` method.
You also can create similar functions to set text Size and other good stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add color to your edit text programatically like:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
// to set text color using RGB code
et.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

You can do it in XML as well like:

```
android:textColor="#FF0000"
```

Or better if you first create a xml definition for colors in **/res/values/mycolor.xml** like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="red">#ff0000</color>
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
<color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
</resources>
```

and set color of editText like :

```
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

and programatically like :

```
 et.setTextColor(R.color.white);
```

Hope it helps;

Comment: This is not exactly what I am asking. What you say must be correct, but you have to do it for every textView, one by one, and that is the thing I would like to avoid